# ExactTarget: Problem with Salesforce Integration User Setup in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

i follow this [page](http://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_v5_install_guide/user_configuration/) forSalesforce Integration User Setup in ExactTarget,

and i assign roles and business unit to user, i can't find anywhere can enter Salesforce user infomation,

at user edit page, there is no such "Integrate for Salesforce.com Status".

And i don't know what editon my account is, how can i find this infomation?

Comment: There are several ExactTarget side configuration settings for the integration that may need to be activated. Troubleshooting Salesforce integrations often requires internal information. I suggest submitting a case to help@exacttarget.com. They can also tell you your account type.

Comment: Yes, I didn't activated that. And there are not document that tells me need to do what. Such a bad experience.